# Twist and go front wheel conversion on existing ebike

Tags: conversion, uk

I have new mid motor ebike (Raleigh) and I want to replace the front wheel with a twist and go front wheel conversion with its own separate battery only to get up hills and I will use existing pedal assist for level and downhill cycling -so, is it possible to install front wheel conversion without pedal assist?

---

I am not concerned with the legal aspects of this conversion, purely whether or not I can get away without installing the "pedal assist" part of the front wheel conversion

The existing bike is a [Raleigh Motus Low Step Derailleur Alloy Electric Hybrid Bike](https://www.raleigh.co.uk/gb/en/electric-bikes/motus/) 7 speed, with a Bosch Active Line motor and a Bosch Power Pack Frame Mount 300Wh, 36V battery

The conversion I intend using is a 48V 26" Electric Bicycle Motor Conversion Kit Cycling Hub RR FR Wheel 1000W with a 48v 20Ah battery.

---

[image]

Comment: Without knowing a little more detail about exactly what bike and planned conversion kit, can't see any reason not to.  The front wheel conversions I've seen are independent to whatever the rest of the bike is.   May need to consider local laws though, in some jurisdictions having increased power from two motors may be enough to move your e-bike to a different class of vehicle.

Comment: Only with  a motorbike licence

Comment: What's the wattage of the bike's stock motor ?   What approximate location of the world are you in?   Given "Raleigh" I suspect you're in the UK ?

Comment: Answers for other legal jurisdictions would be useful too, even if its a different place to where OP will be using their bike.

Comment: what's twist and go?

Comment: @njzk2 Twist and Go would be a hand throttle like a motorbike, as opposed to Pedal Assist where you have to push the pedals to get some assist.   PA requires the cranks to be rotating, which makes you look like a cyclist whereas a twist throttle lets you sit on the motorbike like cargo.  In the UK, pedal assist is mandatory, anything else is an electric motorbike.

Comment: I have edited the extra info into the question.  Please use your original account.

Comment: I've added a stock photo of this bike to help readers understand the style of riding, its not a hill-climb rocket bike like I initially thought.   What is the underlying goal of this change - to ride up a steep road ?

Answer (score 1):

**Presuming you're in the UK**, the law states:

> Its electric motor must have a maximum power output of 250 watts (and) should not be able to propel the bike when it’s travelling more than 15.5mph

<sub>From https://www.gov.uk/electric-bike-rules</sub>

There's no specific statement about a bike with multiple motors, but summing the total wattage would be a reasonable first approximation.

If your bike has a 200 watt motor, you could add another 50 watt motor and still comply with the power limit.

However the same page also says that the motor must not provide assistance at speeds over 15.5 miles per hour ( which is 25 km/h)  
  This means both motors must cut out at that speed.

> Any electric bike that does not meet the (electrically assisted pedal cycle) rules is classed as a motorcycle or moped and needs to be registered and taxed. You’ll need a driving licence to ride one and you must wear a crash helmet.

There is an option for "type approval" of bikes, but that's done by the manufacturer and your modified bike would not comply

---

Upshot, your modified bicycle would class as an electric motorbike and needs to carry a license plate.

The only way you can do what you want legally is to not ride it in public spaces.  That's no roads, no trails or tracks, no parks, no space where people can go without owner's permission.

You have to walk or trailer this bike to/from the site.  You cannot ride it.

You can only ride it on land you own, or where the owner has given specifically you permission.

Comment: The same page says twist and go e-bikes are also ruled out.  They were allowed at one point, and I found e-bikes  much better in that mode (no unexpected acceleration when timing gaps in traffic).  Also note that a lot of illegal e-MTBs are use, as are a lot of illegal conversions.  A crackdown is overdue, especially on the use of the latter in urban areas.

Comment: @ChrisH yeah the law lags and implementation of law is even slower.  From my office window I see E-scooters travelling faster than cars doing the posted limit of 50 km/h.

Comment: @Criggie Generally speaking, a condition to have a license plate is that the "vehicle" is conform. That is not fulfilled with a DIY conversion.

Comment: @Renaud this might be another regional difference, but here all motor vehicles that require registration have to display a number/licence plate.   There's no distinction between one-off custom and a commercially sold vehicle.   We have a process called LVV certification for "Low Volume Vehicle".   Once a custom vehicle is certified, its treated like any common car.  My uncle built a 3 wheel motor-trike and went through the whole process over several years and many dollars, but its now a road legal motor vehicle.

Comment: OP also runs the risk of turning into this kind of rider:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeTEXzR-vPE

Answer (score 1):

Even assuming it is legal, it's not technically doable. A kit designed for the rear wheel won't physically fit into a front fork. On a bike like the one pictured, rear wheel hubs have a 135mm width, while the front ones have 100mm.

I'd also have concerns about having a 1000W motor on the front wheel. Bikes are rear-biased in terms of weight distribution (and even more when going uphill or when accelerating), there might simply not have enough traction for this amount of power.

Comment: OP mentions "front wheel conversion" presumably like the old school "hilltopper" which was a replacement front wheel, with some wires etc.  Such a wheel should just swap in, assuming same rim specs and rotor mount.

Comment: I looked at front wheel kits a few years ago (applying for a job in the next city; the direct bike route is rather hilly) and you could certainly get 1kW with a throttle then. For considerably less than a road-legal conversion (@Criggie)